# I want to get the infinite scroll page id

Tags: php, yii, infinite-scroll

I implemented Yii infinite scroll its working fine. When I added Google ads based on given condition its displaying four Google ads. Then when fetching next page, the values are repeating. ie (Google ads-showing empty results) so that I want to GET the infinite scroll page ID.

Please help me how to get the page ID(ie next page ID). I have added my code here :

```
<?php
$post_counter = 0;
$addnum = 0;
foreach($posts as $rec): ?>
<div class="post">
<?php           $rec_id = $rec['recipe_id']; ?>
    $post_counter++;

    if (($post_counter == 7) AND ($addnum < 4)) { 
        $addnum = $addnum + 1;   
        $post_counter=1;
    }
?>

<script>
// Display an ad unit
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

```
 <?php if(isset($addnum)>3)

       echo exit($post_counter)?>
  <?php     
  }    

  ?>
```

i put like this it will work

Comment: i can't understand a thing, please put more code and describe better the things you are referring to.

Comment: ie.. Display x amount of data at start,   for ever scroll 8 amount of data

Answer (score 0):

go to extension/assets/yiiinfinitescroll.js

get ID from js file